# ParametricNDSolve and plotting problem

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have a problem with `ParametricNDSolve`:

```
a = 1; d = 0.13; s = 0.4; f = .1;

eq = c'[t] + I a (Abs[c[t]])^2 c[t] + d (Abs[c[t]])^2 c[t] -s (Abs[c[t]])^2 c[t] - f Exp[-I w t] == 0;

r =  ParametricNDSolve[{eq, c[0] == 0}, c[t], {t, 0, 25}, {w}];
Plot[Evaluate[{Re@#, Im@#} &[c[t] /. r, {w, 1, 10, .1}]], {t, 0, 25}]
```

i have no idea what is wrong here; i checked the documentation center and some posts on similar topic - and i'm still stuck.
Any help appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 1; d = 0.13; s = 0.4; f = .1;
eq = c'[t] + I a (Abs[c[t]])^2 c[t] + d (Abs[c[t]])^2 c[t] - 
    s (Abs[c[t]])^2 c[t] - f Exp[-I w t] == 0;
r = ParametricNDSolve[{eq, c[0] == 0}, c, {t, 0, 25}, {w}];
Plot[Table[Through@{Re, Im}@c[w][t] /. r, {w, 1, 10, .1}], {t, 0, 25}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

Update: various views

```
pre0 = Plot[Table[Re@c[w][t] /. r, {w, 1, 10, .1}], {t, 0, 25}, 
   Evaluated -> True, ImageSize -> 500,  
   PlotLabel -> Style["Plot@Table[Re@c[w][t]/.r,{w,1,10,.1}],{t,0,25}]", 16]];
pim0 = Plot[Table[Im@c[w][t] /. r, {w, 1, 10, .1}], {t, 0, 25}, 
   Evaluated -> True, ImageSize -> 500, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["Plot@Table[Im@c[w][t]/.r,{w,1,10,.1}],{t,0,25}]", 16]];
pre1 = Plot[Table[Re@c[w][t] /. r, {t, 0, 25, 5}], {w, 1, 10}, 
   Evaluated -> True, ImageSize -> 500, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["Plot[Re@c[w][t]/.r,{t,0,25,5}],{w,1,10}]", 16]];
pim1 = Plot[Table[Im@c[w][t] /. r, {t, 0, 25, 5}], {w, 1, 10}, 
   Evaluated -> True, ImageSize -> 500, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["Plot[Table[Im@c[w][t]/.r,{t,0,25,5}],{w,1,10}]", 16]];

Row[{pre0, pim0}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

```
Row[{pre1, pim1}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Re@c[w][t] /. r, {t, 0, 10}, {w, 1, 5}, Evaluated -> True,
  PlotPoints -> 100, BoxRatios -> 1, ImageSize -> 500,
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Mesh -> None, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you guys! and btw. is there a way to plot the c dependence of w without transforming the equation explicitly?

Comment: @BarLac, do the plots in my updated post answer your question re "the c dependence of w without transforming the equation explicitly"?

Answer (score 0):

```
r = ParametricNDSolve[{eq, c[0] == 0}, c, {t, 0, 25}, w];

Plot[Flatten[{Re@#, Im@#} &[Table[c[w][t] /. r, {w, 1, 4}]]], {t, 0, 
  25}, Evaluated -> True]
```

Comment: ok, thanks; also i'd like to make a fourier transform  for this equation, but somehow FourierTransform[eq, t, \[Omega]] is stuck on evaluation (putting a or w instead of omega doesn't work)